# Kendo Ui dropdownlist with ASP.NET MVC5 onSelect function

Tags: asp.net-mvc, drop-down-menu, kendo-ui

I am using Kendo UI Dropdownlist with ASP.NET MVC5. 
I want to write a cookie onSelect:

```
@(Html.Kendo().DropDownList().Name("sss").BindTo(Model).DataTextField("Name").DataValueField("Id")
              .Events(e =>
              {
                  e.Select("onSelect");
              })
              .Deferred()
              )

function onSelect(e) {
            if ("sss" in window) {
                debugger;
                var dataItem = this.dataItem(e.item);
                alert(dataItem.value);
                setCookie(dataItem.value);
            }
        }
```

all the functions are reachable and working fine. but I am getting an:

> undefined

value instead of Id. 
why am I receiving this error? and how can I fix it?

P.S. the Model contain both Id and Name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once you get the dataItem, it *is* an instance of your model used to populate the DropDownList.

So, in order to access the Id field, use the Id field *not* the value field(which your model does not have).

```
function onSelect(e) {
    if ("sss" in window) {
        debugger;
        var dataItem = this.dataItem(e.item);
        alert(dataItem.Id);
        setCookie(dataItem.Id);
    }
}
```

Comment: aha, now I understand where was the mistake. I though it will build a standard dropdownlist or in another way: select, option

Comment: how can I change the selectIndex in the same example to the value in cookie, the cookie function called: getCookie();